# Is setting set_time_limit(0) a bad idea?

Tags: php

I am making changes to a script a freelancer made and noticed at the top of his function he has set the timeout limit to 0 so it won't timeout. Is there any implications to doing this? Or should i properly test his script and work out how long it is taking and if it will timeout on the server?

Edit - Adding more detail.
So its a script that creates a temp DB table and populates it by pulling data from a number of different tables, it then outputs it to a csv using mysql outfile.

Comment: Without context, it's difficult to say if it's good or bad. If it's a daemon script, then it's good. If it's an HTTP response, then it's bad UNLESS - and then there's a ton of reasons when it's good and when it's bad. Basically, your question can't be answered based on info you provided.

Comment: I believe, that this depends on the script's purpose. If you provide a little more detail like what the script does could be of help. In general it is not a critical issue IMO, but it is not recommended, due to server exhaustion in some cases

Comment: With or without the limit, is always good to implement some logging, you can also add performances usage in your logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP docs:

> set_time_limit — Limits the maximum execution time
>
> seconds: The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is
> imposed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

If you set the time limit to zero, it means the script could run forever without being stopped by the PHP interpreter. Most times this is a bad idea, because if you would have a bug in your code which results in an unending loop, the script will run forever and eat your CPU.

A lot of times I've seen this in code without a good reason, so I assume the developer couldn't think of an appropriate timeout and just set 0.

There are a few valid reasons you would want to set a timeout of 0, for example, a deamon script.

Comment: Well yes and no.. As @N.B mentioned in case of a daemon it is required. But without a context it is hard to give a good advice. Stay tuned and if there is a clarification consider updating.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov Thanks, I updated the answer and made it a community wiki, so feel free to improve.