# Execution suddenly stops after long SQL results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a simple code that extracts records from database. The specific part where the problem lies is here:

```
    while ($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $data[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
```

So, I was running a simple `SELECT` SQL from which I was expecting ~100k results. 
If there are more than ~50k results nothing after the `while` loop is shoiwing up, not even a `var_dump`.

But if i `SELECT` one row the results are popping up.

I have no access to the server config. Max execution time is 60s.

Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the php log?

Comment: try to add this in your while : set_time_limit(0);

Comment: Do you really need to manually add 100,000 rows to a variable? How about a [`fetch_all()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?

Comment: Maybe You ran out of memory. What's Your `memory_limit`? Try printing `memory_get_usage()` every few rows to see if You are reaching the limit.

Comment: Why are you querying 100k results? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the query? As @Loek said, do you need to save every row to the `$data` variable? For that many results you are probably running out of memory.

Comment: @Loek Already tried `fetch_all()` but still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a `memory_limit` problem, which allocated only `256M`. Setting the limit to `2048M` with `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M')` solved the problem.

Keep in mind that executing `set_time_limit(0)` is considered a bad practice in PHP because the PHP interpreter will run endlessly. [[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861610/is-setting-set-time-limit0-a-bad-idea) If you script needs this command then you need to optimise it.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the `php.ini` config values from your php code also. Add this as the first line of your function

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

It will change the `max_execution_time` value as infinite

Comment: That's such a bad practice... And that doesn't solve my problem.